# I want store file name with timestap like this dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm:ss, but i am getting exception like below

Tags: java

Please can help any one, below is Exception trace.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\folder\Resumes\xxx_11_24-Feb-2014 5:26:40 PM 
IST_Resume.docx (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Comment: Maybe your path isn't valid. Could you show us some code?

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far? I mean your complete code. Can you paste it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your path description I understand that your program is running in Win OS. So your are using not valid characters is your path: **':'**. The following chars are invalid in windows file names:

```
\/:*?"<>|
```

You should use different time stamp pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure below path exists

```
 C:\folder\Resumes
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows, the file name cannot contain any of the following characters:

```
'\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|'
```

Make sure the folder where you write the file, exists and your file name does not contain any of the above characters.